# Input Error in Very Simple Python Application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python and when running this simple guessing program I get an error at *guess=int(input('Enter an integer: '))* Running Python 3 because the book is based on this version. Thanks in advance!

```
number = 23 
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer: '))

if guess == number:
    print('Congratulations')
    running = False
elif guess < number:
    print('No higher!')
else:
    print('Little lower!')
else:
print('while loop is over.')

print('done')
```

The error:

```
Enter an integer: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../Documents/Python Programs/while.py", line 5, in <module>
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Please fix your indent. Also where are you running this program? Sublime2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3 is not working with Sublime Text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059062/python-3-is-not-working-with-sublime-text-2)

Comment: @jamylak Yes sublime 2 And oops that was a copy and waste mistake, the line in subject is indented though

Comment: @jamylak So I can still write in Sublime text just not build in it? What should I use to build instead?

Comment: There are alternatives, one is SublimeREPL

Comment: This is probably a more appropriate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input It contains links and information

Comment: @jamylak I've just installed SublimeREPL, thanks jamylak :)

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wrong. Once it's fixed the program runs fine under Python3.

```
number = 23 
running = True

while running:
    guess = int(input('Enter an integer: '))

    if guess == number:
        print('Congratulations')
        running = False
    elif guess < number:
        print('No higher!')
    else:
        print('Little lower!')
else:
    print('while loop is over.')

print('done')
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't the problem. Sublime Text 2 doesn't take any input. The indentation is fine (notice the comments above)

Comment: @gnibbler Sorry that was a copy and paste error into the stackoverflow, thats what my code looks like ^^ Its not the solution

Comment: @JOG-Design, Indeed, from the comments it seems you are running it wrong.

Comment: @Haidro, First mention of sublime was jamylak's comment. My ESP must be done today